# Getting notFound error after domain wide delegation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to set up domain wide delegation with Google so I can have access to a workspace calendar. I've followed through the documentation and here is what I've got so far:

- Service account for the app is set up
- Google Calendar API is enabled for this account
- Generated and saved JSON key
- Added app's account Client ID to Security -> API Controls -> Domain-wide Delegation with correct scopes

App's service account:

[image]

Workspace:

[image]

And here is my simple Ruby code for retrieving a simple calendar event:

```rb
google_calendar_service = ::Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
google_calendar_service.authorization ::Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(json_key_io: File.open(PATH_TO_JSON_FILE), scope: MY_SCOPES)

google_calendars.get_event(owner_email, event_id)
```

Both `owner_email` and `event_id` are correct as I have a working code that uses OAuth2 and it can get the event as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message and the line that throws you this error?

Comment: auth.sub = 'admin@yourdomain.com'  <--- did you add the subject that you want to delegate as.  This needs to be a user on your domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the subject that you are going to delegate as. This needs to be the user on your domain which you want the service account to act on behalf of

Check the authorizer.sub line.

```
 authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
      json_key_io: StringIO.new(File.read AppConfig[:credentials_file]),
      scope: AppConfig[:cal_scope]).dup
    authorizer.sub = @person
    authorizer.fetch_access_token!
```

Comment: Cool, it worked, thanks. However, I was trying to achieve this without 3-Legged OAuth https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby#example-service-account Is it possible?

Comment: well if you are using a service account then you are not using three legged oauth2 flow.  There is a diffrence.  three legged flow would require that a user consent to access, a consent screen needs to pop up.  Service accounts are pre authorized via google workspace.  You just have to tell your code which user to delegate as or to pretend to be.